# How do i get orchestrator-Tenant option in ui path?

Tags: uipath, uipath-orchestrator

[image]

I am unable to see orchestrator-Tenant in the drop down. Is there something we need to install?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you not yet registered your account. You can do that in UiPath Studio or in UiPath Robot.

The Easiest way is via **UiPath Studio**:
[image: UiPath Studio]

Now you should be able to deploy to Orchestrator.

Comment: Hi, When I select View or Change Profile  I get the below options. UI path studio Pro community & Ui Path X studio. Attached above is the screenshot. However, When I select View or Edit License , I am able to see the option from your screenshot but even after selecting community License., I am still not able to see the option public to orchestrator tenant

Comment: I also tried to click on the tenant I created but it looks like I do not have access to the orchestrator.I do not understand why? PFA screenshot got the error message

Comment: Mhh not sure what you see actually. You just shown the profile image. Please show me the "View or edit" of the licence. I updated the image to make more clear to you where to click.

Comment: Added the image. When I select community license it relaunches studio but I still can't' see orchestrator in publish

Comment: got the solution for this .The path in the orchestrator robot had to be https://platform.uipath.com/<account name>/<servicename> Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Yeah absolutely depends on the tenant. The free tenant ist your schema. If you have some paid one it can look very different like I have. Good that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

From your first image. Showing that you are not connected to Orchestrator (Only publish to "Robot defaults" option available)

- You need to connect to Orchestrator so that you can publish to connected Orchestrator.

[Orchestrator Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr6s6.png)

In order to have tenant option your account should be assigned for multiple tenant on such Orchestrator.

For Orchestrator Community edition after connected it will show "Orchestrator - Tenant" as you may expected.

[After Connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EZaq.png)

In order to access orchestrator community edition go to https://cloud.uipath.com

LoL contribution point lower than 10 cannot post picture directly. Vote me if this answer is right to your point ;)